# Django. Философский вопрос о выводе данных без моделей с возможностью изменять в админке

Tags: django, django-admin

Итак, есть блог на джанге. Нужно на одной из страниц сделать так что бы темплейт выводил данные(информацию о сайте, например), которые можно изменять в админке без использования моделей. 
Очевидно, первое что пришло это - создать отдельную модель. Но так как у модели будет только один инстанс - хз насколько это адекватно.

Есть ли для этого дела встроеные инструменты джанги или как можно более органично это сделать?

Comment: додумалась для такого дела создать 'служебную' модель для разных about, footer..... есть еще какие то варианты решения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отчасти вы пришли к правильному методу, но есть нечто другое, используемое в Django. Рекомендую ознакомиться более внимательно с документацией: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/flatpages/